# pandas get the row-wise minimum value of two or more columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I reference the minimum value of two dataframes as part of a pandas dataframe equation? I tried using the python `min()` function which did not work. I am looking for something along the lines of this:

```py
data['eff'] = pd.DataFrame([data['flow_h'], data['flow_c']]).min() *Cp* (data[' Thi'] - data[' Tci'])
```

I also tried to use pandas `min()` function, which is also not working.

```py
min_flow = pd.DataFrame([data['flow_h'], data['flow_c']]).min()
```

```
InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

I was confused by this error. The data columns are just numbers and a name, I wasn't sure where the index comes into play.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(365)
rows = 10
flow = {'flow_c': [np.random.randint(100) for _ in range(rows)],
        'flow_d': [np.random.randint(100) for _ in range(rows)],
        'flow_h': [np.random.randint(100) for _ in range(rows)]}
data = pd.DataFrame(flow)

# display(data)
   flow_c  flow_d  flow_h
0      82      36      43
1      52      48      12
2      33      28      77
3      91      99      11
4      44      95      27
5       5      94      64
6      98       3      88
7      73      39      92
8      26      39      62
9      56      74      50
```

Answer (score 212, accepted):

If you are trying to get the row-wise `mininum` of two or more columns, use [`pandas.DataFrame.min`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.min.html). Note that by default `axis=0`; specifying `axis=1` is necessary.

```py
data['min_c_h'] = data[['flow_h','flow_c']].min(axis=1)

# display(data)
   flow_c  flow_d  flow_h  min_c_h
0      82      36      43       43
1      52      48      12       12
2      33      28      77       33
3      91      99      11       11
4      44      95      27       27
5       5      94      64        5
6      98       3      88       88
7      73      39      92       73
8      26      39      62       26
9      56      74      50       50
```

Comment: Is it possible to add a shift(1) in here or would I need to add a temporary column (e.g. data["flow_c_1"] =  data["flow_c_1"].shift(1)) ? Thx

Answer (score 20):

If you like to get a single minimum value of multiple columns:

```
data[['flow_h','flow_c']].min().min()
```

the first "min()" calculates the minimum per column and returns a pandas series. The second "min" returns the minimum of the minimums per column.

Comment: and if one would want to get the index of the min of min?

Answer (score 1):

One may also transpose and call `min()`.

```py
data['min_flow'] = data[['flow_h','flow_c']].T.min()
```

or call `min(axis=1)` on the underlying numpy array.

```py
data['min_flow'] = data[['flow_h','flow_c']].values.min(axis=1)
```

If no axis is passed, `ndarray.min` is evaluated on the entire array, so for a single minimum value of multiple columns (i.e. minimum of minimums), accessing the underlying numpy array could be useful too:

```py
minimum = data[['flow_h','flow_c']].values.min()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use numpy to reference or get the row-wise mininum of two (or more) columns in another one. Important to specify `axis=1`.

```
import numpy as np
...
data['min_c_h']= np.min(data[['flow_h','flow_c']],axis=1)
```