# What does df.min() do?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

what does this exactly mean? or what does it do?
a is a column in the dataframe
b is another column in the dataframe
both have numbers in each row

```
df['a'] = df[['a', 'b']].min(axis=1)
```

I tried doing the research online but dont seem to find an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each row, it compares columns `a` and `b` and takes minimum one and overwrites column `a` with new minimum values. Check [`pandas.DataFrame.min`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.min.html).

Here is another stackoverflow [question-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33975407/4681316).

Answer (score 0):

df['a'] is referring to the column A as a list

df[['a','b']] is referring to the columns A and B as a DataFrame

The code you have shared gets the minimum value of columns A and B, by row, and updates the respective value in the column 'A'.

Try this code out to make sense of what is going on

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5], 'B': [5,4,3,2,1]})
print(df)
df['A'] = df[['A', 'B']].min(axis = 1)
print(df)
```

Comment: A column isn't type of `list` or sth. else. Pandas columns generally have their custom data types which are series. You can get list from series with `Series.tolist()`